# Menu bar missing on startup Drupal

Tags: drupal

I am running 5.21.1 with Drupal 7.69 (latest at time of posting). It was fine until I upgraded to this version of Drupal. Now I have as issue with the menu bar. When you first log-in the bar does not appear. However, if you then refresh the browser page, the menu appears and works fine after that. I have read all the posts about "menu missing", cleared the caches etc. and checked the .htaccess files but no joy. If you close the browser and then start a new browser session the menu is fine as long as you are still logged in. Has anyone else seen this?

PHP ver is: 7.2.27-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1

Comment: Welcome to civicrm stackexchange. Thanks for including all the relevant details. Can you check your browser console when the menu bar is not showing and see if there are any errors showing. Also is this just for your user or do you see it for multiple users?

Comment: I'm having the same issue on one site but not the others.
Debian with php 7.1
Hopefully I will be able to post more details tomorrow

Answer (score 4):

Hi @yobba I would suggest you look at applying this patch https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/16177 in one site i was associated with this fixed the error for us.

Comment: thanks. I'll test this in the afternoon and verify if it works.

Comment: Hi Seamus. Yes, that fixed the issue. Thanks very much for you quick response and help.

Comment: patch worked for me. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Bumped into the same issue.
added this:

composer civicrm:publish

and now it is working.
(Drupal 9.5.3 / CiviCRM 5.58.1)

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks! (Drupal 10 / CiviCRM 5.60.alpha1